# Mvvmlight and Xamarin Unified API: Property not found

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvm-light

I tried to use the dlls for the unified API on iOS provided by Laurent here:

http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2015/01/porting-mvvmlight-to-the-xamarin-ios-unified-api-64-bits/#respond

and have some issues. I don't know if it a new bug or maybe I am making something wrong.

1) I tried to bind a ViewModel's property to a UI's property :

```
_binding = this.SetBinding(() => ViewModel.IsLoading, () => _myView.IsLoading);
```

`myView` is a custom subview of the `ViewController.View`.

But when running the app, I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Property not found: IsLoading
```

2) Since the first snippet does not work, I tried the following

```
_binding = this.SetBinding(() => ViewModel.IsLoading).WhenSourceChanges(
 () => _myView.IsLoading = ViewModel.IsLoading);
```

It's works fine. But when I am doing something similar with a property that is a `List<T>`, I am receiving a lot of `WhenSourceChanges` events and the UI get updated too many times. That is not very optimal.

If I am listening to `PropertyChanged` events from my ViewModel, I am getting only one update of the list. Thus, it seems that there is no issues with the WM.

Comment: This error indicates that the IsLoading property cannot be found by reflection on the _myView. I suspect it has to do with the visibility of the _myView element. Can you show me how you declare this element, and I will try to repro.

Comment: Nothing complex:
`private bool _isLoading;
    public bool IsLoading
    {
      get
      {
        return _isLoading;
      }
      set
      {
        _isLoading = value;
  }
}
`
I tried also with protected or automatic getter/setter. Still the same exception.

Comment: I also tried to change the visibility of _myView property (public / protected, ...) and still have the exception

Comment: BTW the issue with too many WhenSourceChanges calls should be fixed in the latest release (V5.1)

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell this is a reflection issue. Changing the field `_myView` to a property should correct this issue. For example:

```
private UIView MyView {
    get {
        return _myView;
    }
}
```

Then binding like this:

```
_binding = this.SetBinding(() => ViewModel.IsLoading, () => MyView.IsLoading);
```

You may also be able to create the binding using one of the extension methods that doesn't use Expressions.